# Get filename and rename a file using Jquery in the client browser

Tags: jquery, html

I need to get the name of the file which is browsed to be uploaded in input type file in a form. And then i need to rename it to all alphabets if it contains alphanumeric name.

It is possible in the server side but i need to enable in client side browser.

Comment: You could make a form to create the "appearance" of doing this client side, and use Ajax to actually upload change suggestion and make the change server side. Then flag "success" or "other (error)" to be posted clientside.

Answer (score 0):

To do this on the client side is a security issue. You can't and shouldn't be able to modify or edit a file on the client side.

You can change the name and save it elsewhere in a javascript variable. Then use this variable to process something.

Comment: There is one exception, so to speak. Chrome/HTML5 supports a `filesystem API` for changing filenames stored locally, but that's about as far as that goes

Comment: I guess AJAX will be the best solution. Thanks .